# What is the practical advantage of using mirrored signal outputs eventhough what matters is balancing the wires?

Tags: differential, common-mode, single-ended

Some devices output differential outputs since both wires carry varying signals which are mirrored. Most devices on the other hand output one signal carrying and one GND wire. There is also differential-ended wiring and single-ended wiring. My question will be about "external" interference type of noise(EMI or RFI or maybe capacitive coupling) impinging upon both wires.

After some reading, if I'm not wrong I came to understand the fact that what we really want is "the same noise should appear upon each line" regardless of it is a differential or single ended wiring. And the noise must be common(common mode) so that the differential amplifier can cancel it out.

As far as I understand, there are two main ways to make the noise common. One of them is twisted pairing. The idea here is the wires are very close to each other because they are twisted and the same magnetic filed or electric field hits upon both wires. The second method to make the external noise common is to make the total output impedance(from source to receiving end) of both wires equal, so if an EMI happens both wires would induce the same voltage at the same time.

Upto here was just a summary of my understanding to show/check to whom read this.

Here is a simple illustration of a single-ended and a differential-ended wiring:

[image]

If they are both using twisted wiring and they are all balanced, they would both reject the common mode noise.

So what is the point to send the signals in mirrored fashion if one can balance and twist a single-ended wiring as well? Is that because something is practically easy to establish in differential/mirrored outputs? I really couldn't find a good answer to this.

edit illustration for a comment:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been mentioned by peufeu, if you use balanced differential drivers you create twice the p-p voltage and hence the SNR is doubled because noise can be assumed to remain as it was previously. But, there is another subtlety that was alluded to in the question and this relates to impedance balance.

Quite simply, if the balanced driver had an output impedance of 20 ohm (ignoring the output feed resistor R5) you would need to add 20 ohm to the balancing drive resistor (R6) that connects to 0 volts to keep balance.

But it's a bit harder than this because the output impedance of a driver chip will likely vary across its bandwidth so, it's much easier to use a dual inverting driver and equal values for R1 and R2 (right hand diagram).

Comment: I see I think it is not practically easy to measure the output impedance of a transducer and size and add a resistor to its signal ground R6. Imagine I have 12 transducers single-ended going to same ADC. If I want balance I would have to measure the exact output impedance of each transducer. But in diff ended since we know they are "both" 20 Ohm we can just add 100Ohm to each line or nothing at all. Did I get you correct?

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying, sorry. If you can't estimate the output impedance of a device then use a balanced driver to interface it to the line. Is this what you are getting at?

Comment: I mean practically one doesnt have to deal with measuring output impedances of the signal sources in diff ended outputs. Because as you say diff output wires already have same output impedances. But in single ended I have to measure the output impedance or look at data sheet and add resistor to GND. I was looking for a practical benefit of using diff ended output.

Comment: In a single ended output you have to take account of its output impedance and match that onto the 0 volt wire. You generally don't need to do this when using a balanced driver because of impedance similarity.

Comment: Okay this is the answer and the "practical advantage".

Comment: One more thing please. You wrote "balanced driver". Does that mean mirrored/differential output in your context?

Comment: Yes, a balanced driver means that two two outputs have the same output impedance and their signals sum to zero i.e. one is X volts when the other is -X volts (all relative to some arbitrary constant DC value that is usually 0 volts for audio and (say) 2.5 volts for 5 volt logic digital drivers).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I promised was my last question. But imagine you yourself want to balance a single ended system. And you know the output total impedance and you concluded to add resistor to 0V wire and you think you are done with balancing. Imagine the wiring is twisted as well so you think the system will create the common mode noise and reject it. Is there a technique to create interference and "test" if the system is really rejecting noise? I mean can I experiment if I balance a single ended system? Is there a way to verify?

Comment: Get a cigarette lighter that generates a spark to ignite the gas and hold this near to the wires. Don't ignite the gas of course and don't hold it too near the wires else you may damage the driver or receiver (that's a whole different issue!).

Comment: Woov is this a joke or really a technique? Seriously?

Comment: It's not very repeatable but I've used this technique on digital links in fact I've used a car battery, a 12 volt relay and spark plug with ignition coil. It's very effective but start with the cig lighter to see what happens with a small spark.

Answer (score 3):

Good answer are already posted but I would also add another point.

Single ended systems usually rely on ground as the differential signal. That is fine if the connection is short and you can guarantee the grounds at both ends are the same and you do not have too many of them. Differential transmission removes this reliance and provides some degree of ground isolation and prevents ground loops.

Also, from your question you seem to imply that balancing the impedances and using twisted pairs are alternative solutions. They are not, for best performance you need to do both. In fact, if you don't balance the impedances, using twisted pair is almost pointless.

Also you might find my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/303305/why-is-an-ethernet-cable-not-grounded/303769#303769) interesting.

Comment: Thanks I read your answer but I would be glad if you can answer these 1-) Can you illustrate/(simple drawing maybe) how ground is not an issue in diff ended but can be an issue in single ended. I cannot picture what you wrote thats why. 2-) If I use coax cables do I still need twisting? Is it better to use twisted shielded cables for single-ended than using simple coax cables for distances around 15 meters?

Comment: @user134429 In differential the receiver is looking for a difference in potential between the two signal lines, not a difference in absolute values. You are effectively using a different reference. Using COAX does not help with common mode noise since the ground shields the signal wire from noise, twisted pair shielded cable is better.

Comment: Thanks. I plan to balance a single ended system . So first I have to change the coax to shielded twisted pair then. Imagine you yourself want to balance a single ended system. And you know the output total impedance and you concluded to add resistor to 0V wire and you think you are done with balancing. Imagine the wiring is twisted as well so you think the system will create the common mode noise and reject it. Is there a technique to create interference and "test" if the system is really rejecting noise? I mean can I experiment if I balance a single ended system? Is there a way to verify?

Comment: @user134429 that is a whole other thing and beyond the scope of this answer. You should post that as a new question.

Comment: I see. But regarding what you've written: "twisted pair shielded cable is better." I now use coax and the shield of the coax is earth grounded in receiving end. And the source is floating. If I change to shielded twisted pair. Should I use one wire of the pair as ground? Or should I use shield as ground?  Because there will be 3 wires now. One pair and a shield. Should I just not connect shield any where and use one pair as ground?

Comment: @user134429 Using twisted two wire shielded cable is best for differential signals or what you have indicated as single ended balanced (Which is really differential) where the shield is connected to ground at one end only. Usually whichever end is the primary end and or has a real ground connection. However, it often depends on the setup too, there is some wiggle room in there.

Comment: Thanks I will start to implement this soon. To be sure I added this crude illustration of mine here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHkWC.png So the red is signal, dark blue is the AGND, gray is the shield. The shield and AGND will be wired together in receiver end (which is earth referenced). In source end the AGND and shield is "not" connected. Light blue cylinder is the plastic cover of the wires. I would be glad if you verify if I understood you correct, here is my illustation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHkWC.png

Comment: @user134429 https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyEcK.jpg The grounds are/can be different.

Comment: Sorry for digging it but in your drawing the AGND(dark blue) and the shield(grey or in your case light blue) is not connected together in any end. Shield should be connected to AGND at one end or not?

Comment: @user134429 that is correct.. the should not be connected together. The ground from the left is only a reference for the signal on the right. The shield ground should only be connected at one end.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. In my system the input channels/signals are floating(isolated from protection/mains earth) and they all go to an ADC as single ended. And their grounds are all connected at the ADC/receiver end. This common ground for all signals/channels is then connected to the mains earth through desktop PC. This is called single-ended earth grounded" system. But if I switch to twisted shielded system, I again have to connect all signal grounds to earth ground. And if I connect the shield it means they are again connected together. Did you get my confusion?

Comment: @user134429 If it's already single ended ground and said ground does not carry heavy currents then you can connect the shield at both ends. However, the ground you are passing back with the signal is a voltage reference from the far end, not a ground per se. You do not want that line to carry anything but the return current for the primary signal itself.

Comment: Is this single ended connection okay then in this illustration?: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHkWC.png On the left side the source/sources is/are floating(Shiled is not connected anywhere at all) and on the right side/receiver side the AGND(dark blue line) and the shiled(gray line) is connected together and they both goes to mains earth/protection ground.

Comment: @user134429 NO... Think about where the signal and it's reference are coming from. IN your example the signal is sourced on the left and the reference is on the right. That does nothing for common mode noise.

Comment: @user134429 if you want to join the ground, use my drawing and hook the shield to ground at both ends.

Comment: But than there will be ground loops(?)

Comment: Oh AGND will be only connected to shield at one end

Comment: I see so we dont want shiled to float at one end right?

Comment: @user134429 it's not a ground loop since the signal ground is just a reference to a high impedance input.

Comment: Ok I will make e new drawing and ask again

Comment: I hope this is what you meant: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu8KK.png I wanted to redraw it more clear way. Is this correct now?

Comment: @user134429 why are you having such a hard time grasping this...... https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK9Yl.jpg

Comment: In the system I have the system must be single ended "earth referenced" at the ADC side. In your picture the AGND is not earth referenced at the receiver end. And in your example source is not floating as well.

Comment: @user134429 GRRR.. then this conversation has nothing to do with your original question......

Comment: I gave up I dont understand this I asked you my last drawing is correct or not it seems it is not correct since u offer another drawing which doesn't match my situation. Thanks anyway

Comment: @user134429 If this is for a single ended analog signal to an ADC, your better off going with coax..

Answer (score 1):

> So what is the point to send the signals in mirrored fashion if one can balance and twist a single-ended wiring as well?

2x more voltage swing, thus dynamic range and SNR doubles.

For high-speed signals, driving the cable differentially also reduces the amount of radiated noise. On a PCB, it keeps return currents out of the ground plane. For logic signals (LVDS) it also reduces the amount of noise and ground bounce at the driver side, by making the power supply current of the driver relatively constant and independent of signal. On the receiver side, equal and opposite signals cancel as they couple through parasitic caps, so this also reduces noise.

Consider USB3: if the drive wasn't differential, you'd need 2x more voltage swing for the same noise margin, also you'd need more elaborate common mode filter (ferrites) to reduce radiated noise.

Comment: I thought in mirrored outputs the wires are already balanced(they have the same output impedances from manufacture) and one does not have to spend time on balancing. But in single-ended one has to measure the output impedance of the source's signal and add a corresponding resistor to GND to balance the wires. I was thinking this was the reason.

Comment: Btw regarding your first argument. One can easily send 2x voltage swing by just doubling the output voltage in single-ended output as well(?). Could you explain this why SNR increases in differential? Thanks

Comment: Well, you can increase signal level, but not more than the supply voltage... and low voltage is popular these days! Consider an ADC running on 3.3V, can't take input voltage above the supply, so a differential input driven by differential signals doubles dynamic range...

Comment: Also if you want to drive ethernet through 100m of cables, from a 3V3 chip, considering termination resistors eat 50% of the signal, differential drive really helps in feeding as much power as possible into the cable...

Comment: Oh okay that explains why diff ended is mostly used for low level voltages (?)